# How do I use JUnit to test the getter and setter methods of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, junit

I need to write test cases for a Card game. I'm stuck on a getter and setter method for an arrayList. The arrayList holds the cards for a player's hand and takes an object of another class.

```
Card Class  // Describes the cards
Card(int suit, int rank, boolean ID, int points):

// The cards are fractions instead of traditional cards

// Card(0, 0, true(isDouble), 0(extra point)) card looks like 0/0 

Deck Class  // creates cards and hands
static ArrayList<Card> playerFour = new ArrayList<Card>();

public static ArrayList<Card> getPlayerFour() {
    return playerFour;
}

public static void setPlayerFour(ArrayList<Card> playerFour) {
    Deck.playerFour = playerFour;
}

@Test 
void testGetPlayerFour() {
    // Can't figure out
}

@Test
void testSetPlayerFour(){
    // Can't figure out
}


// Some of what I tried
@Test
void testGetPlayerFour() {
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    ArrayList<Card> playerFour = new ArrayList<Card>();
    playerFour.add(new Card(0, 0, false, 0));
    assertEquals(00, deck.getPlayerFour());
}

@Test
void testSetPlayerFour() {
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    deck.setPlayerFour(new Card(0, 0, false, 0);
    assertEquals(00, deck.getPlayerFour());
}
```

I'm not sure if I need `@Before` and `@After` to initiate the `ArrayList` in the test first. All of the reading and examples I can find use `ArrayList<String or Integer>`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular How do [I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **/** When Unittesting you write tests for **your** code. The `ArrayList` is code of the standard library so you don't write tests for it.

Comment: As Timothy said, you don't need to test an ArrayList of the Cards, you only need to test the functionality that you create (which I'm guessing is the Card class).

Comment: Ok thank you, I don't have much experience in writing test cases so I assumed I should write a test for each method in my classes.

Comment: Would I not test the methods for displaying a player's hand then either?

Comment: All of the methods in the Deck class deal with an ArrayList, whether it's adding Cards to them, displaying the player's hand, dealing the deck, or sorting the hands. I can't imagine that I don't need to unit test any of them?

Answer (score 0):

Quickly I will talk about should you test setters and getters. I entirely believe this is up to you, if the functionality inside the setter and getter is important to your product then yes do write unit tests for them.

So, having decided that you want to test these methods then you can try something like the following:

```
@Test
void testSetGetPlayerFour() {
  // Arrange
  Deck deck = new Deck();
  ArrayList<Card> myCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
  Card myCard = new Card(); // You will need to create a valid card here
  myCards.add(myCard);

  // Act
  deck.setPlayerFour(myCards);

  // Assert
  assertEquals(myCards, deck.getPlayerFour());
}
```

I have combined the test for the set and get methods into a single test. This can be considered bad as a unit test should test the smallest part of the code possible. However, in this case, it makes the test code cleaner.

At Diffblue (the company I work for) we have a free trial of our [unit test generation tool](https://playground.diffblue.com). Using this you can put some of your code in (upto 200 lines) and see the unit tests that are generated.